# How do I pass my variable value into my stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I created a variable className and I assigned values to it.
I have another procedure in oracle that sends emails to me.
How do I pass this value into header and body of my email?

```
VARIABLE className varchar2(30)
    :classname := 0;
    BEGIN
     FOR i IN 
     (
        SELECT CLASS_INSTANCE_COUNT , CLASS_NAME
        FROM MODEL_CLASS_COUNTS 
        WHERE TRUNC(COUNT_DATETIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
     )
        LOOP    
          IF i.CLASS_INSTANCE_COUNT = 0 
          THEN 
              :className := i.CLASS_NAME;
              EMAIL('myemail@col.com',  'email header: &className is 0', 'body: count for &className is 0');
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to happen.  You've got a SQL*Plus variable `:classname` and a SQL*Plus substitution variable `&className`.  Is there a reason that you're using either rather than using local PL/SQL variables in your anonymous PL/SQL block (assuming you even want to bother with a local variable)?  Do you want SQL*Plus to prompt the user for a value (in which case you'd want the substitution variable)?  Or do you just want the value to come from the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you don't want to have either a SQL*Plus variable or a substitution variable.  I'm guessing that you just want

```
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 
   (
      SELECT CLASS_INSTANCE_COUNT , CLASS_NAME
        FROM MODEL_CLASS_COUNTS 
       WHERE TRUNC(COUNT_DATETIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
   )
 LOOP    
   IF i.CLASS_INSTANCE_COUNT = 0 
   THEN 
     EMAIL('myemail@col.com',  
           'email header: ' || i.class_name || ' is 0', 
           'body: count for ' || i.class_name || ' is 0');
   END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: yes. I just came back from a walk and realized that I could do this :) This is exactly what I need. Thank you @Justin cave